# Cannot resolve method 'FindViewById(int)' error in android studio

Tags: java, material-design

im trying to make an app that uses the google material design tab view.

this code worked before I wasn't using the material design but now I get the "Cannot resolve method 'FindViewById(int)'"

here it is my code: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B32sjQFrsoGvb2dHOE5UdUJmalk

For some reason, i can't put it here...

Comment: it's with lowercase `f` i.e `findViewById`.

Comment: @Aominè yes it already is